# Can't retrieve data from SQLite Using Multiple Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I'm trying to use 3 different DatabaseHelper methods I've created to retrieve different data from 2 tables -> "spendings" & "transactions" table. I have to use all 3 of these Cursor method in a method in my Main class and I do not know the right way to overwrite the Cursor cuz I have used these database methods such as myDb.getDeletedCategory, myDb.getLatestAmount, and so on. So I think the main problem is how I define my Cursor after "deletedcategory" and what is the right way of "overriding" or re defining a Cursor after using one :-

```
Cursor deletedcategory = myDb.getDeletedCategory(transaction_id, position);
                if (deletedcategory.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddExpenses.this, "No category found !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    deletedcategory.moveToFirst();
                    deletedcategoryis = deletedcategory.getString(0);
                }

Cursor latestamount = myDb.getLatestAmount(position, deletedcategoryis);
                if (latestamount.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddExpenses.this, "No amount found in specific category !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    latestamount.moveToFirst();
                    amountfromdb_ofcategory = latestamount.getDouble(0);
                }

Cursor deletedamount = myDb.getDeletedAmount(transaction_id, position);
                if (deletedamount.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddExpenses.this, "Deleted amount not found !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    deletedamount.moveToFirst();
                    amount_deleted = deletedamount.getDouble(0);
                }
```

Comment: try closing cursor like if(!deletedcategory.isClosed()){deletedcategory.close()},   and check query is query returning data?

Comment: for deleting and updating data we don't need cursor object as return

Comment: So you mean I need to add the "if(!deletedcategory.isClosed()){deletedcategory.close()}" after the whole Cursor deleted category {} and before Cursor latestamount? and "if(!latestamount.isClosed()){latestamount.close()} after Cursor latestamount {} and before Cursor deletedamount?

Comment: yes but I think deleting and updating doesn't require cursor, the deletion may return int and updation as boolean.

Comment: delete should be like 
public Integer deletedcategory (Integer id) {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      return db.delete("deletedcategory", 
      "id = ? ", 
      new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
   } ,   unless you are not fetching data after deletion.

Comment: It doesnt work ! I'm not using the Cursor to delete the data yet, I'm just trying to retrieve the data that the user wants to delete as I will need the data, for example "category" for me to delete that specific category from another table as well.

Comment: The query isn't returning data from Cursor latestamount onwards

Answer (score 0):

You can just literally overwrite an existing cursor.

For example consider the following Database Helper (with 3 methods that return a cursor) :-

```
public class DBHelper01 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "db01";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_SPENDING = "spending";
    public static final String TABLE_TRANSACTIONS = "transactions";
    public static final String SPENDING_COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String SPENDING_COL_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String SPENDING_COL_CATEGORY = "catetgory";
    public static final String TRANSACTIONS_COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String TRANSACTIONS_COl_DATE = "date";
    public static final String TRANSACTION_COL_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String TRANSACTION_TYPE = "type";

    public static final int TRANSACTION_TYPE_ADD = 0;
    public static final int TRANSACTION_TYPE_DELETE = 1;
    public static final int TRANSACTION_TYPE_UPDATE = 2;


    String crt_spending_tbl = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_SPENDING + "(" +
            SPENDING_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            SPENDING_COL_AMOUNT + " REAL DEFAULT 0.0," +
            SPENDING_COL_CATEGORY + " TEXT" +
            ")";
    String crt_transactions_tbl = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TRANSACTIONS + "(" +
            TRANSACTIONS_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            TRANSACTIONS_COl_DATE + " TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP," +
            TRANSACTION_COL_AMOUNT + " REAL," +
            TRANSACTION_TYPE + " INTEGER" +
            ")";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper01(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(crt_spending_tbl);
        db.execSQL(crt_transactions_tbl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addSpending(String category, Double amount) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(SPENDING_COL_CATEGORY,category);
        cv.put(SPENDING_COL_AMOUNT,amount);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_SPENDING,null,cv);
    }

    public long addTransactions(Double amount, int transaction_type ) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TRANSACTION_COL_AMOUNT,amount);
        cv.put(TRANSACTION_TYPE,transaction_type);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_TRANSACTIONS,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getLatestTransaction() {
        return mDB.query(TABLE_TRANSACTIONS,null,null,null,null,null,TRANSACTIONS_COl_DATE + " DESC","1");
    }

    public Cursor getTotalTransactionAmount() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"sum(" + TRANSACTION_COL_AMOUNT + ") AS summed_amounts" };
        return mDB.query(TABLE_TRANSACTIONS,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public Cursor getAllTransactions() {
        return mDB.query(TABLE_TRANSACTIONS,null,null,null,null,null,TRANSACTIONS_COl_DATE + " ASC");
    }
}
```

and the following Activity that invokes the 3 methods (after initially adding some data)  and then dumps the Cursor after each use :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper01 mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr; //<<<<<<<<<< THE CURSOR THAT WILL BE OVERIDDEN

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper01(this);
        mDBHlpr.addSpending("TEST",123.45);
        mDBHlpr.addTransactions(133.42,DBHelper01.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ADD);
        mDBHlpr.addTransactions(127.45,DBHelper01.TRANSACTION_TYPE_DELETE);
        mDBHlpr.addTransactions(111.11,DBHelper01.TRANSACTION_TYPE_UPDATE);
        mDBHlpr.addTransactions(133.42,DBHelper01.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ADD);
        mDBHlpr.addTransactions(127.45,DBHelper01.TRANSACTION_TYPE_DELETE);
        mDBHlpr.addTransactions(111.11,DBHelper01.TRANSACTION_TYPE_UPDATE);

        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getAllTransactions(); //<<<<<<<<<< First write to cursor
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mCsr);
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getLatestTransaction(); //<<<<<<<<<< Overwrites the Cursor
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mCsr);
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getTotalTransactionAmount(); // Overwrites the Cursor again
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mCsr);
        mCsr.close();
    }
}
```

The resultant output (confirming that each Cursor is different) :-

```
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@5345bd2c
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: 0 {
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    _id=1
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    date=2018-10-30 11:17:31
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    amount=133.42
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    type=0
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: }
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: 1 {
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    _id=2
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    date=2018-10-30 11:17:31
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    amount=127.45
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    type=1
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: }
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: 2 {
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    _id=3
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    date=2018-10-30 11:17:31
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    amount=111.11
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    type=2
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: }
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: 3 {
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    _id=4
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    date=2018-10-30 11:17:31
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    amount=133.42
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    type=0
10-30 11:17:31.937 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: }
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: 4 {
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    _id=5
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    date=2018-10-30 11:17:31
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    amount=127.45
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    type=1
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: }
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: 5 {
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    _id=6
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    date=2018-10-30 11:17:31
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    amount=111.11
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    type=2
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: }
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: <<<<<



10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@5342f0e4
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: 0 {
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    _id=1
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    date=2018-10-30 11:17:31
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    amount=133.42
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    type=0
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: }
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: <<<<<



10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@5342f6e8
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: 0 {
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out:    summed_amounts=743.96
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: }
10-30 11:17:31.941 1252-1252/axtest.axtest I/System.out: <<<<<
```